# Could someone confirm this filming location?

Tags: film-location, hannibal-tv

I was watching *Hannibal*, and thought I recognized the museum from a visit to Toronto years ago (which is where I know they film most of the show). The episode is called "Naka-choko", but I couldn't' find any of the locations.

Here are some pictures: 
[image]

[image]

Specifically if you know the name of the museum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the [Royal Ontario Museum of Natural History](https://www.rom.on.ca/en/exhibitions-galleries/galleries/natural-history/james-and-louise-temerty-galleries-age-dinosaurs) which is, as you thought, in Toronto. On the page linked, there's a series of stills from the James and Louise Temerty Galleries of the Age of Dinosaurs which includes the image below:

[image: Royal Ontario Museum Dinosaurs exhibit]

Which looks to be the same room as the second image in your question.